# Google Sheets App Script permissions limiting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Limited permission to SpreadsheetApp without requiring "Untitled project needs your permission to access your data on Google." I know with the new Macros there is a special permission only for the spreadsheets the Macro is installed on, and with onEdit no permissions are needed due to limiting the scope to only the spreadsheet. Is there any object or method I can use to avoid needing this overreaching permission to simply edit the spreadsheet with say a script connected to an image, or am I stuck with shoving everything in onEdit.

Answer (score 7):

You can define explicit scopes in your manifest file. Google explains how to set explicit scopes [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes).

You can view the full list of available scopes [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) and some specifics around add-on scopes [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-scopes).

Specifically, it's worth calling out the `spreadsheets.currentonly` scope as it's not clearly listed as an available scope.

```
{
  ...
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"
  ],
  ...
}
```

[image]